# Clap options with derive macros fails to compile in rust clap 3.0.0-beta.5

Tags: rust, clap

I'm trying out the "Using Derive Macros" example on [the index page](https://docs.rs/clap/3.0.0-beta.5/clap/index.html#using-derive-macros) for the latest beta version of clap:

```
// (Full example with detailed comments in examples/01d_quick_example.rs)
//
// This example demonstrates clap's full 'custom derive' style of creating arguments which is the
// simplest method of use, but sacrifices some flexibility.
use clap::{AppSettings, Parser};

/// This doc string acts as a help message when the user runs '--help'
/// as do all doc strings on fields
#[derive(Parser)]
#[clap(version = "1.0", author = "Kevin K. <kbknapp@gmail.com>")]
struct Opts {
    /// Sets a custom config file. Could have been an Option<T> with no default too
    #[clap(short, long, default_value = "default.conf")]
    config: String,
    /// Some input. Because this isn't an Option<T> it's required to be used
    input: String,
    /// A level of verbosity, and can be used multiple times
    #[clap(short, long, parse(from_occurrences))]
    verbose: i32,
    #[clap(subcommand)]
    subcmd: SubCommand,
}
...
```

Unfortunately it fails to compile:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling ex v1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/hwalters/git/home/ex)
error: cannot find derive macro `Parser` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
5 | #[derive(Parser)]
  |          ^^^^^^
  |
note: `Parser` is imported here, but it is only a trait, without a derive macro
 --> src/main.rs:1:25
  |
1 | use clap::{AppSettings, Parser};
  |                         ^^^^^^

error: cannot find attribute `clap` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:3
  |
6 | #[clap(version = "1.0", author = "Kevin K. <kbknapp@gmail.com>")]
  |   ^^^^
  |
  = note: `clap` is in scope, but it is a crate, not an attribute
...
```

I tried to find the full example file "examples/01d_quick_example.rs" in the tar file for [this GitHub tag](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta.5), but it does not seem exist there.

I appreciate this is a beta version, but is this functionality expected to work, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you enable the `derive` feature for clap in Cargo.toml? :)  I have made that mistake so many times

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.  If you would like to post an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 43):

In clap, use `features = [ "derive" ]` in `Cargo.toml` to enable the ability to derive :)

## update

@stein below makes a good point of expanding the answer:

> To "use" means: in the [dependencies] section, specify clap with a
> line similar to: clap = { version = "3.1.0", features = ["derive"]} – 
> Stein Feb 19 at 13:00

Please +1 their comment :-).

This means, in your `Cargo.toml`

```ini
[dependencies]
# ...
clap = { version = "3", features = ["derive"]}
```

Comment: if you're like me, check if you forgot the `#[derive(Parser)]` before any `clap()`

Comment: To "use" means: in the [dependencies] section, specify clap with a line similar to:
`clap = { version = "3.1.0", features = ["derive"]}`